# iOS/android でクロスプラットフォームの課金システムは許容される？

Tags: ios, android, アプリ内課金

iOS/Androidのクロスプラットフォームなアプリを考えています。
共通の独自のZアカウントというものにユーザーがログインして使う仕組みで、
アプリ内でコンテンツを買って読んだり、サブスクで一ヶ月全コンテンツ読み放題！とかをしようと考えています。

この際、iOSのアプリでコンテンツを買う時はAppStoreの課金システムを使いたいです。
同じく、AndroidではGooglePlayが提供している課金システムを使いたいです。

その上で、あるユーザーがZアカウントを作り、iOS版のアプリにログインして、AppStoreの課金システムを使ってコンテンツAを購入します。
その状態で同じユーザーが同じZアカウントでAndroid版のアプリにログインしたら、(AppStoreで購入した)コンテンツAが見れる状態にする事は、AppStoreやGooglePlayの規約的に許されるのでしょうか？
もちろん、Android版のアプリで買ったコンテンツをiOS版のアプリで見る事も行いたいです。

技術的にはZアカウントに課金状態を紐付けるだけで難しい事は無いと思うのですが、ストアの利用規約で許されるのかを懸念しています。

自分の認識だと、昔のKindleアプリがそれに近い挙動だったけど、結局今では許されていないからダメなんだろうと思っていたのですが、
ニコニコ動画のアプリやクリップスタジオ、ジャンプ+のアプリで同じような事をしていて「あれ、もしかして許されるのか？」と疑問に思って質問をさせていただきました。

ニコニコ動画のアプリで確認しましたが、同じニコニコ動画のアカウントでログインしたら
iOS版アプリでアプリ内課金でプレミアムを購入出来て、それをAndorid版アプリで反映させる事が出来ました。

Comment: 参考: 過去の類似質問 - [各OSまたいだ外部課金について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/22136/3060)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結論だけ先に書くと「詳しいところにコンサルをお願いしましょう」になります。

論点がいろいろあって、

1. iPhoneアプリ(Androidアプリ)でのサービス提供で、外部の課金プラットフォームを利用すること
2. AppStore(GooglePlay)での課金を、iPhone(Android)アプリ以外でのサービス提供に利用すること
3. アプリそのものの実装(外部課金への誘導の可否とか)

1 は問題ありません。多プラットフォームで展開してるアプリのほとんどがこうなっています。

2 については、実際のアプリの実装を見ると多分OKな気がしますが、提供されるコンテンツやサービスによっても取り扱いが変わる部分もあるので、質問内容だけでは判断ができません。逆に言うと、質問内容で判断に必要な詳細が提供できていない、ということは、外部サービスを使ったサービスの提供に必要な知識が不足している、ということです。なので、これは知識のある人を見つけてくるしかありません。

もう一つ、クロスプラットフォームでやるということは、課金側のIDとサービス側のIDとそれを紐付けるIDの相互の紐付けと管理が必要です。紐付けだけならともかく、パスワードを忘れたので別のID作ったとか、Apple→Googleに切り替えたとか、支払い止めたとか、ビジネス的にも技術的にも管理はものすごくめんどうです。

さらに、質問見ると著作権が絡んできそうなコンテンツっぽい匂いがします。こうなると、権利処理やそれにともなくお金の処理も発生します。

結局、このあたりまるっと誰かに面倒見てもらわないといけないので、詳しい人に最初から入ってもらった方が良いです。

Comment: 詳しい解答ありがとうございます。2について詳しく教えて頂きたいです。コンテンツは平たく言うとKindleの本的なもので、ゲームではありません。どのような情報が必要でしょうか。「取り扱いが変わる部分がある」という事は、AppStoreやGooglePlayの規約に「xxxの様なコンテンツならOKでそれ以外はこういう使い方はNG」という意味でしょうか。
この質問はAppStoreやGooglePlayの利用規約的にどうか？という事に絞りたくて、技術論や(AppStore/GooglePlay以外の)法律や権利者とのやり取りについてはこの質問では一旦大丈夫です。

Comment: 「詳しいところにコンサルをお願いしましょう」と書いてるとおりです。アダルトコンテンツみたいに単純にアウトなものから、コンテンツそのものはセーフでも換金性があるとかでビジネスプラン的にアウトみたいなパターンもあります。